# Why doesn't this show as a link on my site?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, getelementbyid

Trying to get the link within my variable "product" to work with "Link naar website" in blue on my screen. Instead it shows as bold text... which I can't click on.

```
var product = [
  'plantenwinkel.nl',
  'https://www.plantenwinkel.nl/image/data/templates/plantenwinkel/plantenwinkel.jpg',
  '6,30',
  'gratis',
  'https://www.plantenwinkel.nl/krulpitrus-juncus-effusus-spiralis-siergras?utm_source=tradetracker&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_campaign=feed&option=57498'
];

document.getElementById("product_logo").innerHTML = '<img src="'+product[1]+'" alt="'+product[0]+'" />';
document.getElementById("product_prijs").innerHTML = '<p>€ '+product[2]+'</p>';
document.getElementById("product_verzendkosten").innerHTML = '<p>'+product[3]+'</p>';
document.getElementById("product_link").innerHTML = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'+product[4]+'">Link naar website</link>'; //Why doesn't this link work??!?!?!?
```

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MWIT.png)

Comment: You need the `<a>` tag. `<link>` tags are for adding stylesheets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `a` tag, change this:

```
document.getElementById("product_link").innerHTML = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'+product[4]+'">Link naar website</link>';
```

To:

```
document.getElementById("product_link").innerHTML = '<a href="'+product[4]+'">Link naar website</a>';
```